# Добавить набрынный текст из input и вывод с помощью кнопки в textarea

Tags: html, вёрстка, текст

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом, при нажатии button нужно чтоб текст который был написан в input добавился в textarea

Bla Bla BLa Bron kod:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <input  name="bron" value="">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="button">Vstavit</button>

  <script>
  $("button").click(function(){$("textarea").val($( "textarea").val() + '')})
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("textarea").html($("input[name=bron]").val() + " bron kod")
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<input name="bron" value="">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="button">Vstavit</button>
<textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: есть одна проблема,  чтоб при нажати кнопки текст вставлялся перед словом bron kod,   а то он удаляет весь текст

Comment: ну так добавьте этот самый "bron kod" в добавляемый текст. Внесла правки в код.

Comment: $("textarea").text() поправьте

Comment: а это уже дело вкуса text или html  использовать в данном случае

Comment: а как сделать чтоб при нажатии вставить , чтоб добавлялся в начало текста а не в конце?  извините меня заранее ,  новичок пока , и спасибо за помощ

Comment: Последний вопрос был очень глуп )) , Спасибо за помощь Kjuri, 
Тема закрыта.